# Am a I square repdigit?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

### Your Task

You will write a program or function to return a truthy value if the integer inputted to it is a square repdigit, and a falsy value if it is not.  A repdigit is an integer that contains only one digit (e.g. `2`, `44`, `9999`).  For the purpose of this challenge, a square repdigit is a repdigit that is the square of a different repdigit.

### Input

An integer, in base 10.

### Output

A truthy/falsy value that reflects whether the input is a square repdigit

### Examples

```
0 --> falsy
1 --> falsy
2 --> falsy
4 --> truthy
9 --> truthy
11 --> falsy
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest bytes wins.

Comment: So, the integer provided *and* it's square root must be repdigits?

Comment: Is this really much different from [Is this number a repdigit?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125133/is-this-number-a-repdigit)

Comment: `define f(x) = answer from is this number a repdigit; return f(n) & f(root n);`

Comment: So we are asking if input is 4 or 9?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Or 0 or 1.

Comment: @Adám No they must be squares of *different* repdigits.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, I missed that bit.

Comment: `4` and `9` are indeed the only repdigits that are squares of other repdigits. The last two digits of any repdigit>10 squared contains two different values: `1..1 -> ..21, 2..2 -> ..84, 3..3 -> ..89, 4..4 -> ..36, 5..5 -> ..25, 6..6 -> ..36, 7..7 -> ..29, 9..9 -> ..01`. If you square `8..8`, the last three digits are `544`.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear. At least, it is *now*.

Comment: Yes, but I approve of its closing anyway.  I hadn't realized it was just a trivial matter of hard-coding 4 and 9 in.

Answer (score 9):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), <s>6</s> <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
+
```

Abuses the way that Neim deals with lists.

`+` pushes the numeric literal `49` to the stack.

Then,  attempts to pop a list from the stack, and Neim implicitly converts `49` to `[4 9]`. It then pops another element, which is the input, provided implicitly. Finally, it checks that the input is in the list.

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%2B%F0%9D%95%9A&input=9)

Comment: Umm, can't you use one of the constants for `49`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Forgot all about them :P

Comment: And wait Neim is competing? o_O it even beats Jelly

Comment: Why the heck does Neim have a built-in for `49`? :P

Comment: @ETHproductions It has a built-in for all numbers `1-156`. As it's an incomplete language, characters not assigned are automatically assigned as a variable. It used to have numbers up to `180` (also it was Erik's idea to add these :P)

Answer (score 7):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>20</s> <s>17</s> 10 bytes

```
&4-:5-*!.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X81E18pUV0tRz@H/f0sA)

*Thanks @ovs for -7 bytes!*

### How?

```
&4-:5-*!.@    Initial pointer direction >  (Input: 9   )
&             Get input as integer         (Stack: 9   )
 4-           Subtract 4                   (Stack: 5   )         
   :          Duplicate                    (Stack: 5, 5)
    5-        Subtract 5                   (Stack: 5, 0)
      *       Multiply                     (Stack: 0   )
       !      NOT                          (Stack: 1   )
        .     Print as integer             (Stack:     )
         @    End of program
```

### Proof that `4` and `9` are the only valid square repdigits

The last two digits of any repdigit>10 squared are two different values, except `8..8`:

```
 n    n^2 % 100
--------------
1..1     21
2..2     84
3..3     89
4..4     36
5..5     25
6..6     36
7..7     29
8..8     44
9..9     01
```

`88^2 = 7744`, and the last three digits of `8..8^2` is `544`.

Comment: +1 just for the proof.  I really wish I had checked to make sure there were more repdigits before asking this.

Comment: @Gryphon You could use [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/60043) to prevent issues like this.

Comment: Yes, I should have posted this in the sandbox first.

Comment: `&4-:5-*!.@` for 10 bytes

Comment: @ovs Wow, that's awesome. I couldn't think of using a NOT...

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 11 bytes

```
#==4||#==9&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
e4,9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/VRMfy////lgA)

<s>Note: if you disprove me, I'll edit. This returns a truthy result only if the input is 4 or 9.</s>

[Junghuan Min ninja'd a proof...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125973/41024)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, JavaScript, Java, 12 bytes

```c#
n=>n==4|n==9
```

For Java replace `=>` with `->`.

Or a version more in the spirit of the challenge, C# only, for 61 bytes:

```c#
g=n=>n.Replace(n[0]+"","")==""
n=>g(n)&g(System.Math.Sqrt(n))
```

Comment: The 12 byte solution works for JS too.

Comment: @Shaggy I suppose it will work for Java too

Comment: Doesn't Java use `-` instead of `=` for arrow functions?

Comment: @Shaggy Oh yeah... added a comment about it because it is really the same code.

Comment: Was about to post a Java answer when I saw this. +1

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
49S¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxDL40M7DS///twQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

Just tests for membership of {4,9}

```apl
∊∘4 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHV2POmaYKFgCuQpGXGkKJkBsCcSGhgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 19 bytes

```
.pl3e1:0|>e1:0|<+1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fryDHONXQyqDGDkzaaBvq/v//3@xrXr5ucmJyRioA)

This is as far as I can tell actually the shortest way to check "is `n` 4 **or** 9?"

Will output `1` if input is `4` or `9`, otherwise will output `0`

### Explanation

```
.pl3e1:0|>e1:0|<+1-  Implicit input from commandline args
.p                   Duplicate, pop duplicate, push prime factors
  l3e                If there are exactly 3 items in stack..
                     (2 prime factors plus original input)
     1               ..Push 1
      :              Else
       0             ..Push 0
        |            Endif
         >           Move last item to start
          e          If 2 prime factors are equal..
           1         ..Push 1
            :        Else
             0       ..Push 0
              |      Endif
               <     Move first item to end
                +    Sum last 2 items
                 1-  Subtract 1
                     Implicit output.
```

Comment: That's not very golfy, considering the language name is Brain*golf* and it is beaten by Java.

Comment: @Okx it's bad at complex conditionals

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, <s>65 58 53</s> 46 bytes

I have code-copying issues.

```
@if %1 neq 4 if %1 neq 9 echo 0&exit/b
echo 1
```

Return 1 for truthy value, 0 for falsely value.

Comment: Unrolling the loop to `@if %1 neq 4 if %1 neq 9 echo 0&exit/b` is a few bytes shorter. (FYI my solution is 26 bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 22 bytes

```php
<?=$argn==4||$argn==9;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkomTNZW8HFLOFCNia1NRAWZbW//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 18 bytes

```
lambda n:n in[4,9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczLCoMwFIThVzm7k6AFb21V0BexWVhKqNAeJWaRPH066eJbDPzMEf17lzbZ6ZE@6/f5WklGoU2WrhxMsrujiEVLKJguM3Fxeqes2sSroLXOQcg5V1xyDQ200MEVbnCHHobc/MOajRnpcPkn6vQD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), <s>39</s> 25 bytes

Solution can be shorter for sure.

old:

```python
n=input();print(n in ['0','1','4','9'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRCNPITNPIVrdQF1H3RCITYDYUj1W8/9/AA)

new:

```python
print(input()in['4','9'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzOvoLREQzMzL1rdRF1H3VI9VvP/fwA)

---

From this: "a square repdigit is a repdigit that is the square of a different repdigit."

Let z='ζζζζ...' be the square repdigit.

**Case 1 z<10:**

<s>0² = 0</s>

<s>1² = 1</s>

2² = 4

3² = 9

4² to 9² are not square repdigits.

**Case z>10:**

Lets assume there is an y∈ℕ with y²=z and y='xxxxx..'

We have just tested all single digits, so if there is an y with y² = z, then it has to be y>10.

So we can write y = x[10°+10¹] + x[10²+10³+...]

Then it is: y² = x²[10°+10¹]² + r  = x² [10° + 2*10¹] + r, with r only containing summands of power >1.

Comparing z='ζζζ..' with y² we get: x²=ζ and 2x²=ζ, hence x=0.

⇒ The only square repdigits are <s>0,1,</s> 4 and 9.

Comment: I don't understand the `+ r` part.

Comment: Emphasis: a square repdigit is a repdigit that is the square of a *different* repdigit.

Comment: @JungHwanMin: You are right "r>100" is not clear. Now, as r=r₂*10²+r₃*10³+..., it should be clear, that r just contains all dezimals >=10².

Comment: I think you can write `[10⁰+10¹]` as simply `11`. Also, I can't understand what the `r` is for.

Comment: Welcome on the site! Nice first answer! (as Okx mentioned, 0 and 1 are not square repdigits though)

Comment: Also you have unneded whitespace in `in [`, and you don't need to use `n`.

Comment: Try `print(int(input())in[0,1,4,9])`

Comment: @Okx Umm, you kept `0,1,` in. And `int(...)` isn't of any significance when this is corrected.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I just tried to keep it as close to the existing solution as possible. But yes, 0 and 1 should be removed.

Comment: @Okx Can? They must be removed otherwise this doesn't follow the still current rules...

Comment: I edited the answer, so that it should be more obvious what 'r' means.

Comment: Updated according to your comments. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 17 bytes

```js
a=>!((a-4)*(a-9))
```

```js
f=
a=>!((a-4)*(a-9))

for (i=0;i<12;i++) console.log(''+i+' -> '+f(i))
```