# Smaller-Base Palindromes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, base-conversion, palindrome

For the purpose of this challenge, a smaller-base palindrome (SBP) is a number which is palindromic in a base between 1 and itself (exclusive), and is not a repdigit in the same base.  For example, 5 is a SBP because it is a palindrome in base 2 (101).  The first few SBPs are `5,9,10,16,17,20,21,23,25,26,27,28,29,33...`

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that, when given an integer `i` as input, returns/outputs the `i`th SBP.

### Input:

An integer `i` where `0 <= i < 1,000,000`.

### Output:

The `i`th SBP.

### Test Cases:

```
12 -> 29
18 -> 41
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14038/69331)

Comment: It's not in the OEIS? Weird...

Comment: @Rod 6 is a repdigit

Comment: @NieDzejkob thanks, I overlooked that part

Comment: Surprisingly, this is actually (relatively) difficult in some golfing langs.  (relatively meaning ~15 bytes instead of ~3)

Comment: @Emigna, thank-you, fixed.  I did these by hand, so I apparently missed that one.

Comment: @NieDzejkob, I agree it is weird that it isn't in the OEIS, but unless I was wrong about something between 5 and 26, it isn't.

Comment: @Gryphon you should submit it

Comment: What is a "repdigit"? I assume it's a single digit repeated? This is never clarified or defined.

Comment: Also, what is the result for `i = 999,999`?

Comment: as your examples are 0-indexed, shoudn't your `i` be in range `0<=i` ?

Comment: From one of gryphon's closed challenges, [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125947/am-a-i-square-repdigit?rq=1 ], A repdigit is an integer that contains only one digit (e.g. 2, 44, 9999) which explains why 3 isn't an SBP since 11 is a palidronme but all the digits are the same

Comment: Every number is a repdigit in some base. Do you mean to exclude only base 10 repdigits?

Comment: How is 33 not a repdigit?  It's given as an example of a SBP. For that matter how is 5 not?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Ignore that previous comment, I thought it was about another challenge.  I'll delete it now.  What I meant on *this* challenge was that only palindromes in smaller bases that are *not* repdigits count.

Comment: So 5 is a SBP because it is a palindrome, but not a repdigit, in base 2.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>133</s> 119 bytes

-3 thanks to Ovs

-5 thanks to Lynn

1-indexed

```python
j=i=0
n=input()
while n:
 j+=1;l=[];N=i
 while N:l+=N%j,;N/=j
 if{i%j}<set(l)>l==l[::-1]or j>i:n-=j<i;i+=1;j=1
print~-i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc6xDoJAEATQmv2KDQkJBIge5cHS0/ADhALhkL2cB0GMGqO/jqD1TGbe9FyG0SZrO3YKCV3XXTUxHcES2@m2@AHcBzYKrQTUIYnUUFWnJTHgPyilCan0dJSWB9KA3L/Y0@/sqhbfBLkhMpWUsajHGXXO0sakM05539IkYJrZLp@Y1@0boN9aBbLFubFn5YsIExFIcH6YDWiay6lrJBbgqIdqcXevXw)

Comment: What does `.;` do in `while N:l+=N%j,;N/=j`?

Comment: @NieDzejkob the comma? it makes a tuple of size 1. in python a tuple can be written as `(1, 2, 3)`, but for a tuple of size 1 you must place an extra comma at the end as `(1,)`

Comment: Rolling the loops into one is slick. Here’s [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc6xDoJAEATQmv2KDQkJBIge5cHS0/ADhALhkL2cB0GMGqO/jqD1TGbe9FyG0SZrO3YKCV3XXTUxHcES2@m2@AHcBzYKrQTUIYnUUFWnJTHgPyilCan0dJSWB9KA3L/Y0@/sqhbfBLkhMpWUsajHGXXO0sakM05539IkYJrZLp@Y1@0boN9aBbLFubFn5YsIExFIcH6YDWiay6lrJBbgqIdqcXevXw).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
µNDLвʒÂQ}ʒË_}gĀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/F58Lm05NOtwUWAsku@Nr0480/P9vagAA)

**Explanation**

```
µ                 # loop until input matches are found
 N                # push current iteration number
  D               # duplicate
   L              # range
    в             # convert to each base
     ʒÂQ}         # filter, keep elements that are equal to their reverse
         ʒË_}     # filter, keep elements that are not all equal
             g    # length
              Ā   # is trueish (not zero)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
bṖEÐḟŒḂÐfµ#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//YuG5lkXDkOG4n8WS4biCw5BmwrUj4bmq//8xOQ)

-2 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan), one being for, well, obvious stuff >_>

Explanation:

```
bṖEÐḟŒḂÐfµ#Ṫ Special quick behavior requires full program
bṖEÐḟŒḂÐf #  Get the first (STDIN number)th integers with truthy results under this
             function starting from 0
 Ṗ             Make range [1..tested integer)
b              Convert the tested integer to each base in the range above
  EÐḟ          Remove repdigits (i.e. negative filter by all-equal)
     ŒḂÐf      Keep palindromes (i.e. filter by is palindrome)
         µ Ṫ Pop the last element of the integer list formed
```

Comment: One byte save: `Ṗ⁸b` -> `bṖ`

Comment: Another byte save - [take input and remove the `5`](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//YuG5lkXDkOG4n8WS4biCw5BmCsOHI@G5qv//Ng)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Except your second byte save won't really work. Dunno what was I thinking with the first one though >_>

Comment: At what point will the result deviate? My thinking: the `5` stops the monad's argument acting as the starting point (without that a monadic link would deviate from `6` up since it would start counting `n` of the `#` at the wrong point) but a niladic link uses `0` implicitly here, so allows us to use a full program that takes input from STDIN to save a byte.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ...niladic? I'm calling it as a monad here, the "last argument" *is* included. EDIT: take input? now I get it

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
e.f_I#ft{TjLZS
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f_I%23ft%7BTjLZS&input=1&debug=0)

1-indexed.

Explanation:

```
e.f_I#ft{TjLZSZQ Trailing ZQ is implicit
 .f            Q Find the first Q (input) positive integers that return a truthy result for
             SZ    Make range [1..Z (tested integer)]
          jLZ      Convert Z to each base in the range
      f            Filter by "non-repdigit"
        {T           Unique elements of T (tested element)
       t             Remove first element
   _I#             Filter by Invariant with Reverse (i.e. palindrome)
e                Take last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 125 bytes

```python
n=5
i=input()
while i:
 n+=1;b=1
 while b<n:
	b+=1;l=[];a=n
	while a:l+=a%b,;a/=b
	if{n%b}<set(l)>l==l[::-1]:i-=1;b=n
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCsIwDIDhc/MUvQw25pAKgqSLLzJ2aGCyQIhFKyLis1d01@@HP7/KerVDrUZHEBLLj9J28FxFFy8I3noKkSmA34xHQ3D8U6VpjokM3JYSak@p4V1Me2Jwcnlbw5/xvpRWu7MS6YQ4hBll@E8N8k2seKs1nL4)

`n` represents the integer we test for SBP-ness as we count up.

`i` is the input: it is decremented each time `n` is an SBP.

We loop over bases `b` from 2 to `n` inclusive* and compute the (backwards) base-`b` representation of `n`: this is `l`. The only real magical part is the chained comparison `{n%b}<set(l)>l==l[::-1]`:

- `{n%b}<set(l)` makes sure `l` contains at least two distinct digits (i.e. `n` is not a repdigit), by checking that `{n%b}` is a *strict* subset of `set(l)`. (We know `n%b` is in `l` as `n%b` is the last digit of `n` in base `b`.)
- `set(l)>l` is always true because of how Python sorts types.
- `l==l[::-1]` checks that `l` is a palindrome.

One final trick is using `b=n` instead of `break` to exit the loop.

(*It’s safe to include `n` in the loop, as `n` in base `n` is always `10`, which isn’t a palindrome. (`while b<n` looks like we exclude `n`, but note where the `b+=1` is!))

Comment: wut? 2 little changes from mine deserved another answer? but the explanation was nice

Comment: I didn’t base my answer off yours. I just read the challenge, wrote an answer, and posted it.

Comment: but they were identical, except for the `while b<n` instead of a `for` and the `break` bit

Comment: Yes, because almost everything about this problem is about as straightforward as it gets. (What am I gonna do, *not* loop `while i:`? *Not* increment `n`? :)) Over on [anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org/) users regularly come up with nearly identical answers. (See also: our [policy on duplicate answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/3852).)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 53 bytes

```apl
{{∨/∧/¨((1<≢∘∪)∧⌽=⊢)¨(⍵+1)⊥⍣¯1⍨¨1↓⍳⍵+1:⍵+1⋄∇⍵+1}⍣⍵⊢2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Tq6kcdK/QfdSzXP7RCQ8PQ5lHnokcdMx51rNIEij3q2Wv7qGuRJlDqUe9WbUPNR11LH/UuPrTe8FHvikMrDB@1TX7UuxksZQUmH3W3POpoBzNrgQqBDKB2o1qgVQqHVgCVKhgZAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 83 bytes

```perl6
{(5..*).grep({grep {.Set>1&&[.reverse]eqv$_},map {[.polymod($^a xx*)]},2..$_})[$_]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPu/WsNUT09LUy@9KLVAoxpEKlTrBaeW2BmqqUXrFaWWpRYVp8amFpapxNfq5CYCZaP1CvJzKnPzUzRU4hIVKiq0NGNrdYz09IAKNKNV4mNr/xcnViqAjTc0suZCcCys/wMA)

### Expanded

```perl6
{
  # create a list of SBPs
  (5 .. *).grep(
    {
      # find out if the current value is a SBP

      grep
      {    # parameter is $_
        .Set > 1              # is there more than one distinct digit?
        &&
        [.reverse] eqv $_     # is it the same in reverse?
      },
      map
      {    # parameter is $a
        [                     # put into an Array so it is not a one shot Seq
          .polymod( $^a xx *) # convert into new base
        ]
      },
      2 .. $_                 # possible bases
                              # (don't need to exclude $_ here)
    }

  )[ $_ ]                     # index into the list of SBPs
}
```